# how can i solve "Launch Failed" problem in flex

Tags: apache-flex

Recently I have installed the flex in my pc. but after complete a simple project when i run the project it shows the error given bellow.

CreateProcess: "C:\Program Files\InternetExplorer\iexplore.exe" "C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\Flex Builder 3\testproject\bin-debug\testproject.html" error=3

How can i solve it?

Arif

Answer (score 1):

Solution of the above problem.

Just go to this way:

1. Select Preferences Dialog box. (Window > Preferences).
2. Select General > Web Browser.
3. Select a web browser from the list of web browsers installed on your system.
4. Click Apply and OK for perfection.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Program Files\InternetExplorer\iexplore.exe` isn't generally the path for Internet Explorer. Is it possible you manually changed this path to be incorrect? If so, fix your path settings and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your browser location...

See "Changing the default web browser" here http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compile_debug_4.html